# Creating a graph from a Hermitian matrix that is $d$-sparse

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

In a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508139) (page $6$, lemma $2$) I am reading, there is a graph defined for a Hermitian matrix $H$ as ....

Consider a Hermitian matrix $H$ of dimension $2^n \times 2^n$ for some positive integer $n$, where there are no more than $d$ nonzero entries in each column. Let $G_H$ be the graph associated with $H$ whose vertex set is indexed by $\{0,1\}^n$. Each vertex corresponds to a row or column number, and there is an edge between vertex $x$ and $y$ if the matrix element $H_{x,y}$ is non-zero, and since $H$ is Hermitian, then necessarily $H_{y,x}$ is non-zero.

The author then states : "edge labels are then indexed from the set $\{1, \ldots, d \}^2$". This is where I am confused. For a given column, there will be at most $d$ entries, so that if $y$ is a vertex representing a column value, then it will have $d$ neighbours. But if $y$ represents a row value, then a given row can have more than $d$ entries, so I am not sure what is going on here. Moreover there are $2^n$ columns and $2^n$ rows.  I would think there would since there is at most $2^n d$ entries, then the edges would be labelled $(\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1, \cdots d\})$

Afterwards the author writes : "If $(x,y)$ is an edge of $G_H$ such that $y$ is the $i$'th neighbor of $x$, and $x$ is the $j'$th neighbor of $y$, then the edge $(x,y)$ is labeled with the ordered pair $(i,j)$ for $x \leq y$, or $(j,i)$ for $x \geq y$".

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a link to the paper?

Comment: @broncoAbierto done.

Comment: Read on. Labels can be duplicated: "This labeling is not quite an edge-coloring...". They assign labels to edges without requiring that each edge have a unique label.

Comment: @broncoAbierto, I'm not sure this is really the answer I'm looking for. Where does the indexing set $\{1, \cdots, d \}^2$ come from in the first place? I've read the entire paper.

Comment: I've only read that bit so I might be missing something, but I don't see a problem with the process. They propose a labelling scheme and it just so happens that the labels are of the form $(i,j)$, with $i,j \in \{1,\dots,d\}$.

Comment: @broncoAbierto I think the issue is since any vertice $x$ can be considered a row  in the case of $H_{x,y}$ being non-zero, or a  column in the case of $H_{y,x}$ being non-zero, and any column vertice has at most $d$ neighbours, so that any vertice has at most $d$ neighbours.

Comment: Maybe the heart of my confusion is on what the vertices represent exactly. It says they correspond to a row or column number, what does that mean?

Comment: @broncoAbierto Also in a Hermitian matrix if any column has at most $d$ non-zero entries, than any row has at most $d$ entries. Ok I think I understand now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96286/discussion-between-integratethis-and-broncoabierto).